# `Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process` when I restart Apache each time?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

My server is centos 7.4 with Apache 2.4.6.
Each time when I `systemctl restart httpd`,2 messages will added to `/var/log/secure`.Looks like :

```
Jan 19 8:23:48 localhost polkitd[493]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5739:174943 (system bus name :1.119 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jan 19 8:23:49 localhost polkitd[493]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5739:174943 (system bus name :1.119, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I had to reboot the box to fix this.

I'm sure there's a better solution, but in absence of that... kick it all over.

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue For me, Apache would not start at all with this error, so I figured I would answer that a reboot fixed this for me.  Since nobody else at all has even responsed to this question, please accept this admittedly small amount of value added minus the criticism.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable SELinux if systemwide security is non critical. Edit the config file found in /etc/selinux/ .Change status of SELINUX from enforcing to disabled. Save and reboot your server.

Comment: The mere suggestion could lead newcomers or other folks down the wrong path.  This should at _least_ come with a bigger, visible warning.

Comment: @YesBarry, try this tutorial https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-selinux-on-centos-7-rhel-7-fedora-linux/

Comment: SELinux has nothing or little to do with Polkit. I can conceive of no reason why a system with SELinux enabled in permissive mode would result in this error.

Comment: https://stopdisablingselinux.com

Comment: I be rather bored when stupid people repeat at vomitom disable seLinux, buy a brain instead...

Answer (score 1):

I got this message because of wrongly placed certificate and key files.
Once I got these sorted with the apache config, apache started fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file name. The startup script name in the unit file was different than the actual file in init.d

Answer (score 0):

The "real" culprit is `systemctl` which executes `/usr/bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent` and then invokes `pkttyagent`, which communicates with the policykit daemon which generates the log messages. I think the idea is that systemctl first readies itself to verify from the user via the tty that it can do the operation without checking if it needs to verify the user.

You can verify that this is the case by running the command slightly differently:

```
systemctl --no-ask-password reload httpd
```

Now, the polkit message will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Otheus's post pointed me in the right direction.  But in the end, Apache told me what was wrong.  On CentOS 7 I did:

tail /var/log/httpd/error_log
Which had a line like:
[:error] [pid 122064] Unable to verify certificate 'Server-Cert'. Add "NSSEnforceValidCerts off" to nss.conf so the server can start until the problem can be resolved.
So I just:
echo "NSSEnforceValidCerts off" >> /etc/httpd/conf.d/nss.conf

And that fixed the issue so I could fix my certs (which I couldn't do without Apache running)...